# Get the EditorState(DraftJS) from DB with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

I want to repopulate the editor's state with the values i have saved to Firebase.

OnSubmit:

```
sendNotes = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let contentState = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent()
    let note = { content: convertToRaw(contentState) }
    note["content"] = JSON.stringify(note.content);
    this.props.createNote(note.content);

};
```

NoteAction:

```
export function getNote() {
return (dispatch) => {
    database.on("value", (snapshot) => {
        dispatch({
            type: LOAD_NOTE,
            payload: snapshot.val(),
        });
    });
};
```

}

noteReducer:

```
export default function (state = {}, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_NOTE:
        return action.payload;
    default:
        return state;
}
```

}

REDUX/firebase:

```html
{
  type: 'LOAD_NOTE',
  payload: {
    '-MNOwBIWNqY_ZFDO4ILs': '{"blocks":[{"key":"c27el","text":"ASD!!!!!!!!!!!!","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}}],"entityMap":{}}',
    '-MNOyHLvaORxEmuuJmzJ': '{"blocks":[{"key":"c27el","text":"HELLO WORLD","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}}],"entityMap":{}}',
    '-MNOyP50oGHRLiP3T5_h': '{"blocks":[{"key":"c27el","text":"This is a REDUX STORE","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}}],"entityMap":{}}'
  }
}
```

MapStateToProps:

```html
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        note: state.notes,
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getNote })(TextEditor);
```

My Code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getNote();
}

componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
    if (nextProps.note !== null) {
        let item = "";
        _.map(nextProps.note, (note, key) => {
            return (item = note);
        });

        this.setState({
            editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(item))),
        });
    }
};
```

The code is working but I'm not 100% sure about these lifecycle methods & if the code i have written is 'stable'. I am stuck with this, please :).

Comment: if it's working, it looks fine. tougher part about draftJS is ensuring you saving the correct data to database, and retrieving them.

Comment: write it to the question